# store shared_ptr to container with base class

Tags: c++, optimization, stl, c++17, shared-ptr

I want to store some data to container. For example I have such code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <map>


class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Class1 : public Base
{
public:
    Class1() : Base() {}
    ~Class1() {}
};

class Class2 : public Base
{
public:
    Class2() : Base() {}
    ~Class2() {}
};

class Class3 : public Base
{
public:
    Class3() : Base() {}
    ~Class3() {}
};

std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>> myContainer;

void save(const std::string& id, std::shared_ptr<Base> obj)
{
    auto obj1 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Class1>(obj);
    if (obj1)
    {
        std::cout << "save obj1" << std::endl;
        myContainer.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
            std::make_tuple(id),
            std::make_tuple(std::move(obj1))
        );
    }
    
    auto obj2 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Class2>(obj);
    if (obj2)
    {
        std::cout << "save obj2" << std::endl;
        myContainer.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
            std::make_tuple(id),
            std::make_tuple(std::move(obj2))
        );
    }
    
    auto obj3 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Class3>(obj);
    if (obj3)
    {
        std::cout << "save obj3" << std::endl;
        myContainer.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
            std::make_tuple(id),
            std::make_tuple(std::move(obj3))
        );
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Class1> a1 = std::make_shared<Class1>();
    std::shared_ptr<Class2> a2 = std::make_shared<Class2>();
    std::shared_ptr<Class3> a3 = std::make_shared<Class3>();

    save("id1", a1);
    save("id2", a2);
    save("id3", a3);

    std::cout << "size is " << myContainer.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But function `save()` has too much complicated implementation. How to make it easier? Somehow to get correct object type and invoke `save()` once but not in every checking. Maybe it possible to implement it with `std::variant` or `std::tuple`? What is much optimized solution you can propose?

Comment: Is it correct that your `save()` function should do nothing if passed a pointer to an actual `Base` or a pointer to some other derived class?  It should only save anything if the pointer happens to point to a `Class1`, `Class2` or `Class3`?

Comment: I am trying to determine what kind of object there and then move it to container

Comment: needing to know the type is normally an indication of a design flaw.  Why do you need t know that type?  You save function can just be `myContainer.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple(id), std::make_tuple(std::move(obj))`

Answer (score 2):

You seem to understand virtual functions.

Your entire save function could be implemented as:

```
void save(const std::string& id, std::shared_ptr<Base> obj)
{
    std::cout << "save " << obj->name() << std::endl;
    myContainer.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
        std::make_tuple(id),
        std::make_tuple(std::move(obj))
    );
}
```

`name()` would be a `virtual` function that returns the correct string for the type.

Note that this implementation always saves the pointer passed to it, while your implementation may not save anything.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've provide a shared pointer containing the real class instead of a `std::shared_ptr<Base>` when calling the function, you can rewrite this as a template:

```
template<class T>
char const* TypeName();

template<>
char const* TypeName<Class1>() { return "obj1"; }

template<>
char const* TypeName<Class2>() { return "obj2"; }

template<>
char const* TypeName<Class3>() { return "obj3"; }

template<class T>
void save(const std::string& id, std::shared_ptr<T> obj)
{
    std::cout << "save " << TypeName<T>() << std::endl;
    myContainer.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
        std::make_tuple(id),
        std::make_tuple(std::move(obj))
    );
}
```